# Add value at the beginning of an array in react-native hook

Tags: react-native

I am functional component I am using hooks to update the state of the array locationData

```
   const c = {
      title: inputValue,
    }
setLocationData([...locationData, c]);
```

This is working fine, but now I want to add the value at the beginning of the array, and not at the end.

Edit:

I also have a problem to delete an item from the array. I want to delete one item, but more are deleted

```
  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    console.log(index)
    var temp = locationData;
    var temp = locationData.splice(index, 1);
    setLocationData(temp);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just switch the position in the array.

```
setLocationData([c, ...locationData]);
```

You should also be aware of other methods like [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) etc...

**Update: Using Splice**

This relates to part 2 of your question with regards to removing from specific index.

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To
> access part of an array without modifying it, see slice().

So your codes should be similar to the following

```
var temp = [...locationData];
temp.splice(index, 1);
setLocationData(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still struggling to remove one item at a specific location from the array. Can you please help? I edited the code

Comment: updated answer. Splice does not return a new array.